# Android Device Screen Flicker

Tags: unity, scene

I have made sudoku type game. I am about to complete my game in 2d. At present, my game run smoothly on higher configuration devices such as Sony Experia Sola, Samsung Note 2 and Google Nexus.

But it creates screen flickering problem in my HCL ME tablet. I don't what is problem going on. I notice that when I load prefabs then it start flickering problem. If I don't create any prefab then it don't flicker at all.

At present my development game resolution is 2048x1536. So friends I need support from your side. If you want any more detail then I will provide any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can able to resolve this problem by creating game using 2d toolkit. But using default Unity 2d I can't able to get success.

Basically I understand the problem was, In Unity 2d, each displayed texture occupy size in graphical memory of device. If same sprite loaded 10 times then texture atlas created 10 times for the sprite.

Using 2d toolkit, single sprite collection created created so there was no problem of loading same atlas multiple time. Here I share my general experience then I got from working some hours.

If you have any suggestion then please share it also.

**EDIT:**

Hey friends, I found another solution to resolve flickering problem. I pasted here to help other members.
**Sprite Packaging** helps me to overcome this issue in native Unity 2d game development.
For this I don't use **2d Toolkit** as I suggested above.

I got nice help from following tutorial section.
[Unity 2D Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61532/unity-2d-tutorial-getting-started)

In this **Sprite Packaging** explained nicely.
I think above information provide enough information to solve this problem.