# Load single texture atlas for multiple sprite

Tags: unity, sprites, rendering, texture-atlas

Recently, I am developing sudoku game. For this, I have created multiple grid 9x9,12x12 and 15x15.

For this numbers are repeated so multiple sprite renderer are created and it load same number texture multiple time.

So I want single number loaded single time only no repetition texture occur in graphical memory.

Because of this problem I am facing following problem that I already posted.

[Android Device Screen Flicker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71566/android-device-screen-flicker)

I want suggestions to overcome this problem from your side.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you're asking. What have you tried already and what about it didn't work?

Comment: @Byte56, I don't want to discuss anything with you.

Comment: OK, I'm not asking you to discuss anything with me, I'm asking that you clarify your question so it can be answered. If you don't want to do that, that's fine. You're just less likely to get the help you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think, I have found answer for this question also. In edit section of answer, I have posted answer of this question.

[Android Device Screen Flicker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71566/android-device-screen-flicker)

At present I am not marking it as correct because I want suggestion from other developers also. So please share your knowledge regarding this.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.